# How can I get my IOGear GCS632U KVM switch to work?

Tags: 10.10, kvm-switch

I bought a KVM switch and I'm trying to use it to have it connected to my main PC (win7) and my new machine I just installed ubuntu on. I hooked it up properly, and tried using it. It worked when switching from the win7 machine to the ubuntu one, but after the (1st and only) successful switch, ubuntu just didn't seem to recognize my mouse or keyboard.

Basically when I tried it the easiest was to explain what happened was it only worked with Win7. When I switched over to ubuntu by doing a [scroll-lock] [scroll-lock], my keyboard and mouse were not recognized. However, the lights on the keyboard and mouse did work when on ubuntu, but they didn't function, and since keyboard wouldn't function, I couldn't do a [scroll-lock] [scroll-lock] to switch back to the win7 machine. So I was basically locked in to ubuntu with no mouse or keyboard, and I had to unplug the keyboard/mouse USB's and d-sub to plug the monitor d-sub back into win7 computer to type up this thread and google the issue. Seems some people have had this issue before but I couldn't find a fix...

I am 80% sure it has to do with drivers... *but there isn't any for KVM switches, at least not this one* also I never was unable to find ubuntu drivers/firmware for my mouse and keyboard (Logitech G15 and Razer Deathadder 3500). I don't know how to fix this, perhaps someone super-savvy could write/code a script or work-around or something? I really need to get this thing working, my back is getting sore from bending over and plugging in / unplugging USB/monitor/USB/monitor/USB/USB over and over again lol... And I really would be sad if the constant plugging unplugging of the USB's or the d-sub port would over time damage the ports... I don't want that...

There has to be some way to get this working... 
Can anyone help?

The KVM is an IOGEAR GCS632U

Win7 x64
Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Has the OP abandoned the question

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would check with IOGEAR. Product Info:
Pre-Sales product questions / product information: support@iogear.com

According to them:
The mouse and keyboard console ports on the GCS632U are hardwired for their particular device. These ports emulate the generic connection to the computer and the keyboard port also enables the KVM hotkeys.

Since these console ports are not true USB ports, they are not interchangeable. The mouse and keyboard need to be connected to the proper ports, or there may be performance issues with the peripherals.

The keyboard and mouse ports are labeled with an icon, located at the bottom of the switch.

The mouse connects to the left console port.

The keyboard connects to the right cosole port.